# How do I validate using pytest that my Python code is not logging any stack traces?

Tags: python, pytest, python-logging

I would like to use pytest to check that my function is not generating any stack trace data into logs, e.g. via [logging.exception()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.exception), but the `caplog` object ([docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html)) doesn't contain any information about the stack trace in the `records` or `record_tuples` attributes. What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

From the [LogCaptureFixture docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.LogCaptureFixture) for the `messages` attribute:

> Note that traceback or stack info (from `logging.exception()` or the `exc_info` or `stack_info` arguments to the logging functions) is not included, as this is added by the formatter in the handler.

This exclusion also appears to apply to the `records` and `record_tuples` attributes. The only place I could find the stack trace text was in the `caplog.text` attribute. So my test can do something like this:

```py
assert "Traceback" not in caplog.text
```